# Wrong routing after DNS change on server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a server with multiple websites on it. Every website is working fine.

For a new client, I'm moving a website to my own server. I prepared the server and I changed the DNS settings from the domain to my own server. I'm aware it takes time before the DNS change takes effect.

It looks like the DNS is applied on the network i'm connected to, because the domain is redirecting to my server IP, but the domain is not showing the right website on my server?

When I view the domain on an other network, everything is working fine. This is verified by multiple people on other networks.

I changed the DNS about 9 hours ago. Do I have to wait longer or is it a problem on my server? Isn't it strange the domain is showing the wrong website?

Comment: What exactly did you change in the DNS zone?

Comment: I changed the A and the AAAA record to my servers IP (ip4 and ip6).  The exact same settings are working on other domains.

Comment: have you made a traceroute from your conflicting network? tracert www.server.com

Comment: What does `host yourdomain.com` show on where it works and where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see logs for the request getting to your web server?  If so, then your problem has nothing to do with DNS, and instead is in the virtual host configuration of your web server.

You say 'wrong' web site, but is that wrong web site another site hosted on your server, or something else?  If it is another site on your server, that also would confirm that you don't have a DNS problem.

Comment: Thnx! I checked this out and found that I did not assigned the IP6 ip's to the domain. Also figured out that this was not the only domain in which the IP6 ip wasn't assigned.